# Count if: job is in a certain time interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df1 that contains three columns:

```
No.     Start Time          End Time
1       07/28/15 08:03 AM   07/28/15 08:09 AM
2       07/28/15 08:06 AM   07/28/15 08:12 AM
```

The start and end time represents the start and endtime of a certain job. 
I want to construct a new dataframe that counts the number of active jobs at a certain time at a specific day. Like this:

```
Hours   Number of tasks
0:00    
0:01    
..  
..  
11:59
```

This dataframe should display for every minute of the day how many jobs are active. A job that starts at 8:03 and ends at 8:09 should be counted for the following times: (Because it ends at 8:09 and is not active anymore at 8:09)

```
8:03
8:04
8:05
8:06
8:07
8:08
```

How should I do this in a simple way?

Comment: I did not find a good solution  yet, anyone  with a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a pandas solution, but you could loop and filter.
Quick example base on the hour:

```
import datetime

jobs = [
    (datetime.datetime(15, 7, 28, 8, 3), datetime.datetime(15, 7, 28, 8, 9)),
    (datetime.datetime(15, 7, 28, 8, 3), datetime.datetime(15, 7, 28, 8, 58)),
    (datetime.datetime(15, 7, 28, 8, 3), datetime.datetime(15, 7, 28, 10, 3)),
    (datetime.datetime(15, 7, 28, 8, 3), datetime.datetime(15, 7, 28, 9, 3)),
    (datetime.datetime(15, 7, 28, 10, 3), datetime.datetime(15, 7, 28, 8, 3)),
]
data = {'hours': [], 'active_jobs': []}
for hour in range(24):
    current__active_jobs = 0
    for job in jobs:
        if job[0].hour == hour:
            current__active_jobs += 1
        elif job[0].hour < hour and job[1].hour >= hour:
            current__active_jobs += 1
    data['hour'].append(hour)
    data['active_jobs'].append(current__active_jobs)

print DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: I do not require a panda solution, but the end result must be a dataframe. @cyrbil can jou please write the whole code for me based on df1?