# Good date format on x-axis matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:

```
Time    test
0:05    2
0:06    2
0:07    2
0:08    2
0:09    2
0:10    2
0:11    2
```

This datframe starts at 0:00 and ends at 11:59. I created the following graph with:

```
x = dftestgraph['Time']
y = dftestgraph['test']
plt.ylabel('Number of tasks')
plt.plot(x, y, color="#00a1e4", label="Number of Tasks")
plt.fill(x, y, '#00a1e4', alpha=0.8)
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph]

Why is there a line in the bottom of the graph, that splits my filled graph in half? And I would like to format my x-axis as ( 0:00, 0:30, 1:00 etc.) I tried:

```
plt.xticks(0:00, 11:59, 30:00))
```

However this does not work.
My question is:

- Why is there a line in my graph and how can I solve this?
- How to set the x-axis in the correct format?

Comment: Check that the last data point isn't 0:00 and sending your line back to the beginning of your plot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`plt.fill` basically links the first and last point of the time series to build its polygon. I would use [fill_between](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html) instead.

I've put together a MWE below that shows how it can be done. It also show a way to format the xaxis labels as you wanted, derived from the following posts: [Creating graph with date and time in axis labels with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498510/creating-graph-with-date-and-time-in-axis-labels-with-matplotlib/5502162#5502162) and [Plotting time in Python with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574088/plotting-time-in-python-with-matplotlib/16428019#16428019).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import dates
import datetime

plt.close('all')

#---- generate some data ----

t = [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0) + 
     datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in np.arange(0,12.1,0.5)]
x = np.random.rand(len(t))

#---- create figure and axe ----

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.85, 0.75])

#---- format xaxis ----

# position of the labels
xtk_loc = [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0) + 
           datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in np.arange(0,12.1,0.5)]
ax.set_xticks(xtk_loc)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', direction='out', top='off', right='off')

# format of the labels
hfmt = dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=90, ha='center')

#---- set axes labels ----

ax.set_ylabel('Number of tasks', labelpad=10, fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('Time', labelpad=20, fontsize=14)

#---- plot data ----

ax.plot(t, x, color="#004c99", label="Number of Tasks")
ax.fill_between(t, x, 0, facecolor='#00a1e4', alpha=0.5, lw=0.5)

#---- set axis limits ----

timemin = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0)
timemax = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 12)

ax.axis(xmin=timemin, xmax=timemax)

plt.show()
```

which results in:

[image]

Comment: great explanation and help! Thank's!

Comment: @F1990 Cool. I've updated my example so that now the axis limits are also controlled. The time now run all the way up to 12:00, and not just 11:30.

Comment: Great, I am going to implement it in my own code. Maybe you know also a good solution to my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694538/count-if-job-is-in-a-certain-time-interval